# PHP cURL: how to reconnect with new proxy on timeout?

Tags: php, multithreading, parsing, curl, timeout

This is my code:

```
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    foreach ($companies as $com) {
        $com_cats = count($com->find('span.category-str-list a'));
        if ($com_cats == 1) {
            $chm = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($chm, CURLOPT_URL, $yelp.$com->find('h3.search-result-title a')[0]->getAttribute('href'));
            curl_setopt($chm, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxies[rand(0, $proxiesCount-1)]);
            curl_setopt($chm, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($chm, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($chm, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($chm, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($chm, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragents[rand(0, $uaCount-1)]);
            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $chm);
        }
    }

    $running = null;
    $co_unt = 0;
    $keys = array_keys($list);
    while (($mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running)) == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    while ($running && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
        if ($running and curl_multi_select($mh) != - 1) {
            do {
                $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
                if ($info = curl_multi_info_read($mh) and $info['msg'] == CURLMSG_DONE) {
                    $ch1 = $info['handle'];
                    //$status = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                    $data = curl_multi_getcontent($info['handle']);
                    $workers[$co_unt] = new WorkerThreads($data, $list, $keys);
                    $workers[$co_unt]->start();
                    ++$co_unt;
                    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
                    curl_close($ch1);
                }
            } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        }

        usleep(100);
    }
```

Sometimes requests taking too long time to work, so I've decided to change proxy on every timeout and try connect again. So, how to reconnect with new proxy on timeout?